# HTML - nested ul tags. Font-size changes

Tags: html, nested-lists

I'm trying to make a nested unordered list and the nested ul tag has a larger font size. Here's the line of code I'm using:

```
<ul>
<li>myItem 1</li>
<li>myItem 2
   <ul>
     <li>myItem 2a</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>myItem 3</li>
<li>myItem 4</li>
</ul>
```

Here's my style.css:

```
ul {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-left: 80px; 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

I don't have enough reputation points to include a photo, but you can see the output of the code here:

http://crazyrogue.net/ulexample.jpg

Anyone have an idea why the nested ul font size is larger? I want the entire list to have the same size font.

Answer (score 4):

What's your CSS saying is "every time I enter a `<ul>` tag, I should increase the font size by 1.3x". That's how your inner `<ul>` got bigger font size.

To fix this, add a rule that say nested `<ul>`s keep their parent's font size:

```
ul ul {
  font-size:1em;
}
```

Comment: If, like me, you already selected your `ul` css as a child, i.e. `main ul`, this won't work, because `ul ul` isn't as specific.  Just use `main > ul` instead.  The inner lists should inherit their size.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, I think I just had the exact same problem.  The trouble is that you specified the font-size as 1.3em.  The em is a relative unit, and this makes the font-size of each of your nested lists relative to their parent.  When you nest the  the 1.3em is applied recursively, so your next list has a font-size of (1.3*1.3)em.  If you have a couple of levels of nested lists then you'd get 1.3*1.3*1.3 and so on.

It's worth noting, by the way, that this won't be a problem with all browsers - my new Android phone doesn't give me any problems, but my old one does.

Anyway, something like this should fix the problem for you:

```
ul {
    font-size: 1.3em; /*your original code*/
    margin-left: 80px; 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul li ul {
    font-size: 1.0em; /*stops nested lists scaling*/
}
```

That's what's worked for me.  Of course, the second ul declaration inherits everything else from the first one, so hopefully that should be all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you had a link to live code instead of an image but I suspect there are some global style rules that are tripping you up.  It would be good to make sure you have a [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) for your css and then define the rules you need.  `ul` and `ul li ul` are probably getting different rules so you could fix by defining for both :

```
ul, ul li ul {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-left: 80px; 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old, but if you want to make sure your nested lists stay the same size as the parent when using EM units, try:

```
ul {
  font-size: 1em;
}

ul ul {
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

This tells those nested lists to be 100% the size of the parents.

Answer (score 0):

Change your font size unit from em to rem

```
ul {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin-left: 80px; 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

See the example here:
https://codepen.io/Rajivsarna/pen/abEmrYr